# Is there a way to fetch data from a F5 big-ip conf file using PHP or any other language?

Tags: php, python, automation, f5, big-ip

I'm not familiar with networks but I have a requirement where I have to read a big-ip conf file and store the virtual ltm data in a file.

Example of conf file:

```
> ltm virtual /Common/vs_test {
>     destination /Common/10.01.01.111:80
>     ip-protocol tcp
>     mask 255.255.255.255
>     policies {
>          /Common/adt_vs_test {}
>     }
>     profile {
>        /Common/ADT_DSS_A_G { }
>     }
>     rules {
>        ....
>     }
>     security {
>         ....
>     } 
  }
```

From this file, I need the

> Virtual server name - vs_test
>
> IP:10.01.01.111
>
> Port:80
>
> Security  Policy: DSS_A_G

Can someone help me in figuring this out?

Comment: Regular expressions?

Comment: I am not sure if it can be done because there are multiple LTM's and the data is somewhat unstructured and the conf file keeps updating.

Comment: It might be a good idea to include all that information in the question.

Comment: does it have to be by reading the config file, or is using the iControl REST interface ok? If the latter, I can provide an example for you.

Comment: I think using the iControl REST interface is good. Yes, can you please provide an example like how to fetch the required data from the config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a tmsh script to be used locally on the BIG-IP to query that information, or you can use the iControl REST interface to query it as well. You might end up with more than one query to drill down for precisely the correct information as profiles and policies are buried in subcollections of the parent virtual server object. In one query, however, you can pull back the name, destination (IP+port of the virtual server) and the profile collection items like so with curl or a tool like Postman:

```
https://ltm3.test.local/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual?$select=name,destination,profilesReference&expandSubcollections=true
```

This returns all the virtual servers with only the name, ip+port, and profile information in the following json format (only showing the virtual server with a policy on it for brevity):

```
{
    "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:virtualcollectionstate",
    "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual?$select=name%2Cdestination%2CprofilesReference&expandSubcollections=true&ver=14.0.0",
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "bigvip_443",
            "destination": "/Common/192.168.102.60:443",
            "profilesReference": {
                "link": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~bigvip_443/profiles?ver=14.0.0",
                "isSubcollection": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:profiles:profilesstate",
                        "name": "ASM_asm_test_policy",
                        "partition": "Common",
                        "fullPath": "/Common/ASM_asm_test_policy",
                        "generation": 569,
                        "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~bigvip_443/profiles/~Common~ASM_asm_test_policy?ver=14.0.0",
                        "context": "all",
                        "nameReference": {
                            "link": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/security/bot-defense/asm-profile/~Common~ASM_asm_test_policy?ver=14.0.0"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:profiles:profilesstate",
                        "name": "clientssl",
                        "partition": "Common",
                        "fullPath": "/Common/clientssl",
                        "generation": 553,
                        "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~bigvip_443/profiles/~Common~clientssl?ver=14.0.0",
                        "context": "clientside",
                        "nameReference": {
                            "link": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/profile/client-ssl/~Common~clientssl?ver=14.0.0"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:profiles:profilesstate",
                        "name": "http",
                        "partition": "Common",
                        "fullPath": "/Common/http",
                        "generation": 553,
                        "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~bigvip_443/profiles/~Common~http?ver=14.0.0",
                        "context": "all",
                        "nameReference": {
                            "link": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/profile/http/~Common~http?ver=14.0.0"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:profiles:profilesstate",
                        "name": "tcp",
                        "partition": "Common",
                        "fullPath": "/Common/tcp",
                        "generation": 553,
                        "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~bigvip_443/profiles/~Common~tcp?ver=14.0.0",
                        "context": "all",
                        "nameReference": {
                            "link": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/profile/tcp/~Common~tcp?ver=14.0.0"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:profiles:profilesstate",
                        "name": "websecurity",
                        "partition": "Common",
                        "fullPath": "/Common/websecurity",
                        "generation": 568,
                        "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~bigvip_443/profiles/~Common~websecurity?ver=14.0.0",
                        "context": "all",
                        "nameReference": {
                            "link": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/profile/web-security/~Common~websecurity?ver=14.0.0"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

This is a lot cleaner if you write a script in your language of choice to return only the data you want from your virtual servers, and this can be done from a remote machine against however many big-ip devices you have.

Comment: I have just checked out the DevCentral page and CuRL seems to be the best option. Although, I have worked with CuRL earlier to get the HTTP codes. I was trying to figure out if there is a way to fetch the data using any CuRL options so that I can loop through the conf file and automate it.